# sig-alternate undefined control sequence for copyright and isbn

Tags: acm, copyright

I am getting the following error message while using the sig-alternate class:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.84 \setcopyright
{othergov}
! Undefined control sequence.
l.86 \isbn
! Undefined control sequence.
l.87 \doi
```

What could be the possible reason and how can it be fixed?

Comment: `sig-alternate` isn't a standard class but a quick search takes me to http://ipsn.acm.org/2010/IPSN_Submission%20instructions/sig-alternate.cls. Assuming that is the right link, I notice the code doesn't define `\setcopyright`, `\isbn` or `\doi`, all of which are non-standard anyway. Do you have some instructions saying they should work?

Comment: I received instructions to add these lines from the camera-ready reviewer of an ACM conference. I shall clarify from them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sig-alternate class file available here fixed the problem. There is also a need to download the copyright.sty file.

http://www.acm.org/publications/article-templates/proceedings-template.html/

Comment: copyright.sty is no longer there in that URL. any idea?

Comment: Did you try https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/344936/46219

Comment: Yep, I tried but it didn’t work either.

Answer (score 5):

Note that the source of the problem is that there was an update to sig-alternate in May 2015.

Before May 2015, the copyright text had to be inserted manually into the document. With the recent update, new commands like `\setcopyright` allow to conveniently choose between the texts for copyright-transfer, publishing-license, or open-access. In the last step of the ACM publishing process you will now be given a LaTeX code fragment which uses the new syntax. The most likely cause of the error is thus that you are trying to use such a new code fragment, but you haven't updated to the most recent template yet.

The solution is what @Sumit suggested: Simply download the most recent `sig-alternate.cls` and `acmcopyright.sty` from the [official ACM site](http://www.acm.org/publications/article-templates/proceedings-template.html/).

Answer (score 3):

As of 2016 the files mentioned by @sumit can be downloaded from the [SIGCHI's GitHub](https://github.com/sigchi/Document-Formats/tree/master/LaTeX) because the link to ACM website does not include the `acmcopyright.sty` file.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure when, but the copyright file is now included in the class file. My issue was that MikTex had an old version of acmart installed. If you open the MikTex package manager you can uninstall the old version of acmart (for me it was 2017), update your package repository, and install the new version.